# What is the limit of this sequence $z_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> The sequence is :
> $$z_n = \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}$$
> where $\{a_k\}$ is a sequence that converges to $\ell$. Prove that >$\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n= \ell$.

They evaluated it using **Stolz Cesaro Theorem**, but I don't understand why when I split the fraction into $\frac{a_1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{n}$,
and then take the limit as $n\to\infty$, then it's $0+0+0+\cdots+0$, so the limit of $Z_n$ is $0$ not $l$.

So what's wrong?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that although as $n$ goes to $\infty$, each element of the sequence goes to $0$, we are summing infinite of them. You can't assume that the sum of infinitely many infinitely small elements is 0.

Comment: If you see that a sequence is the sum of two convergent sequences, then it's perfectly OK to take the limits and add them to get the limit. The same is true if it's the sum of three convergent sequences, or even a hundred. In this case, you are splitting the $n$th term of $(z_n)$ into a number of terms that increases (to infinity) with $n$. This is not permitted. To see why, consider a specific case like $a_n = 1$ constantly, and evaluate $z_n$ (note that $z_n = 1$).

Comment: @RolandKillian - ahhhh stupid me so it's like 0*infinity (indeterminate form) right?

Comment: @TheoBendit - Aha i kinda understand your idea

Comment: Don't use images.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - sorry and thanks for the edit i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = l$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$,

$$|a_n - l| < \epsilon$$

So we can break down this sum

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{a_n}{k} = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{k} + \sum_{n=N+1}^k \frac{a_n}{k}\right) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=N+1}^k \frac{a_n}{k}$$

Letting $\epsilon > 0$ we can define $N$ such that

$$l - \epsilon = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=N+1}^k \frac{l - \epsilon}{k} \leq \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=N+1}^k \frac{a_n}{k} \leq \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=N+1}^k \frac{l + \epsilon}{k} = l + \epsilon$$

And so because $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we get

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{a_n}{k} = \sum_{n=N+1}^k\frac{a_n}{k} = l$$

And our proof is sufficient. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot it helped